# TypeORM not able to generate migrations

Tags: typeorm

I'm attempting to migrate TypeORM from v2 to v3. I have everything working with my new `dataSource.ts` file except for generating migrations. Given this command in my package.json `"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"`, I'm running this CLI command to generate a migration: `yarn typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations/test-migration -d src/dataSource.ts` However I get the following error:

> Error during migration generation:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
> at MysqlQueryRunner.changeColumn....

I was able to locate a [related Github ticket](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3835) to this issue, but the solution presented there was to not have any constructors in the entity class and I have no entity classes that contain a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had a very specific solution that I will go into but I will also walk through the process by which the problem was found which will be more helpful to general people.

### **Exact Problem**

One of our tables had a column that was set as the primary key inside the `@Column` decorator but didn't have the property `unique: true` set as well. It would be great if TypeORM had an explicit check for this that through a useful error message but it is what it is.

### **Discovering the Problem**

To discover the problem the command to generate the migrations was run: `yarn typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations/test-migration -d src/dataSource.ts` in a Javascript debug terminal in vscode with both the "Uncaught Exceptions" and the "Caught Exceptions" breakpoints checked in the Run & Debug window. Once I stepped through the unnecisary errors and found the exception that was thrown in the terminal I was able to poke around and find the values of `clonedTable` and `oldColumn` to identify which table and column was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gabe that there is a column that is missing `unique: true`
in nestJs entity but I was able to detect which column raising the issue by adding a console log in `node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js` in the beginning of `changeColumn` function like

```
    console.log(`changeColumn params`,{
            tableOrName,
            oldColumnOrName,
            newColumn
        })
```

Then I found which column was logged before the error which make the issue